# Files are written to a windows shared drive everyday, but I don't know from where

Tags: shared-folders, windows-networking

There is a shared drive Z:. Everyday a few files get written to it. I assume by a cronjob, or a windows task. Since the shared drive and the folders in it are public, those files could be generated on any server in the network, and written to the shared drive. Now, I can't find which server is generating them... How could I find out where the files are coming from?

Comment: To start, look at the owner of the file in the file's security properties. Otherwise, turn on file auditing for the share and check it the next time the file(s) appear.

Comment: Or, just turn off that shared drive and wait for someone to complain :P